# Is this the PnL you would expect to see for a hedged call option portfolio?

Tags: market-making, delta-hedging, european-options

- You are a market maker.
- Charging no commission, your only aim is to remain market (delta) neutral.
- Therefore you construct a portfolio of the form:
  $$\Pi = -C - w_{1} B + w_{2} S$$
  where $B = K \cdot Z$ is the discounted future strike payment.

Is this the PnL you would expect to see?
[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. There is no scale relative to position size and the chart only seems to indicate some positives and some negatives in pnl, which is probably possible.

Comment: @Attack68: my interpretation: assuming constant vol in a BS framework, given that you delta hedge daily, then what will your hedging error look like considering gamma and theta risk are left unhedged. The error in the image looks zero mean, homoscedastic (stationary), and piecewise linear.

Comment: @Pontus Hultkrantz Exactly. Although when posting I was thinking that the error would be caused by the difference of actual versus implied vol; although it being caused by gamma and theta makes sense as well. The key thing I am trying to check that the hedged option portfolio is a zero mean stationary process; rather that something that behaves more like a linear bond.

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger: right. One could also discuss whether the piecewise linearity is an artefact due to linear interpolation between daily mark to market (draw lines between dots), which in case means that the option has 22 days until maturity.